# How to improve security with text in a url parameter : .php?parameter=text

Tags: php, security, url, parameters

This url contains a parameter with text :

> my-page.php ?id_article=1&alias=article-name

The result after rewritting is :

> 1-article-name.php

For id_article parameter, i made this security :

```
if (isset($_GET[id_article] && $_GET[article] != null && $_GET[id_article] >= 1 && $_GET[id_article] <= 4 && (int) $_GET[id_article])
```

What can i do for alias parameter which accept text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, does alias get from database?

For your exmple :

```
my-page.php ?id_article=1&alias=article-name
```

The result after rewritting is :

```
1-article-name.php
```

My question is : what do you gonna display in `1-article-name.php`, is the content is get from the mysql database?

if so, just use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to sanitize the alias.

Of course, first the alias must not be empty:

```
if(!empty($_GET['alias'])){}
```

and then use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Don't think that: `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, etc are safe.

Please kindly use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function to sanitize your variables if you embed a string in some SQL targeting MySql, you must escape the string with MySql's function for this purpose :

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php) If you embed strings within HTML markup, you must escape it with htmlspecialchars. This means that every single echo or print statement should use htmlspecialchars.

Good luck.

Comment: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Comment: I get alias from database. That's why i want to check i a user is writting non authorized character or malicious code in this parameter. Before the alias are written in the database, i have a function to clean the alias.

Comment: On your situation, checking $_GET['alias'] is not empty, then checking $_GET['alias'] could get from database. I think. your clean function makes you safe.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to sanitize the route in most cases, just check its what your expecting.

```
<?php 
//id_article (Not empty and is numeric and lower then or equals 4)
if(!empty($_GET['id_article']) && is_numeric($_GET['id_article']) && $_GET['id_article'] <= 4){}

//alias (Not empty)
if(!empty($_GET['alias'])){}
?>
```

**Notes:**

If you are deciding if the route will be a selected file eg: `./some_path/1-article-name.php` then you should at least use basename() and check the file exists.

If your going tobe querying the string against a database you should sql escape the parameter or use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements.

Comment: I get alias from the database. They are prepared for urlrewriting (a function cleans the alias before it is written in the DB). What do you mean by "use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements." ?